# How to get a list of all my posts from the Facebook group

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-javascript-sdk

I can get a single post data by `GET /{post-id}`, but how to get list of all my posts on a single group by group-id?

Comment: Do you mean that- you want to fetch all the posts published by you in a group?

Comment: exactly Sahil, only my posts in a group

Comment: which language are you using>

Comment: I'm developing a cordova app with use of cordova facebook plugin (Android & iOS). The format FB.api('... for me it's ok. I just need to figure out how to do that. I think any language it's ok. The rest I will do by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **fql** and query on the [**stream**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table. You can use the following query-

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id='{group-id}' and actor_id=me() LIMIT 1000
```

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3D%27%7Bgroup-id%7D%27%20and%20actor_id%3Dme%28%29)

Permissions required: `user_groups`

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/#columns) you can find the list of fields/columns you can fetch.

**Using the Javascript SDK:**

Since you are using javascript SDK, you can use the following code:

```
FB.api("/fql?q={above-query}", callback() { … } );
```

**Understanding the number of results by FQL:**

1. If you query stream without a `LIMIT`, you will get up to the last 50 posts or the last 30 days worth of items, whichever is fewer.
2. If you give the `LIMIT`, Facebook executes your FQL and returns all posts that match your query.

   Then Facebook filters out the posts that are not visible to your app. This is based on the actor's privacy settings. There is no `visible_to_me` field in the stream table that would allow you to pre-filter your results.

This [blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) explains the same.

Comment: Very strange, but I get an empty data. I use FQL example on the FB Graph API explorer.

Comment: Do you have the `user_groups` permission?

Comment: Yes. I do that with an access token with the user_group permission.

Comment: Maybe in the place of me() I have to put my user_id?

Comment: Then it shall work ! Check your access token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ does it have the required permission. `me()` will work fine, no need to use `user_id` instead

Comment: hmmm, very strange, but I just publish a fresh post, and ... its in data. But why I can't see older posts?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, even with me(), but I can not see older posts, only fresh. Is that a way to get all posts, but not only fresh?

Comment: Well you can add `LIMIT` to get all posts, check the edit. And pls dont foget to accept ans if helped!

Comment: I put a limit 100000000000, but it returns only some of posts, not all of them. Any idea? I just need to keep a list of all posts on a group, older and newer at any time.

Comment: I'm not sure what wrong are you doing but this works. I've tested it many a times.

Comment: Yes it shows all posts by me. I kept the limit that you tried.

Comment: Look, I check that on two different groups, in one its show me my posts from 1 of April, and on another it show me from 24 March. Not older. May be it depends on how many posts is in the group? I don't know. It's looks working, but not as I wish.

Comment: If its not showing all posts even with limit, it looks like a bug, you can post the bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/. They will respond you. Hope it helps!

Comment: **Sahil** thank you very mach for your help. I will try to contact to facebook. Hope to get an answer.

Comment: Looks like I found a solution. The problem is that the query looking just in some amount of posts. When I used for example ... adn created_time < 1387307883, It shows me up older posts. So every time i retrieve some posts, on the next query i have to user created_time < {created time of last showed post}

Comment: Oh yes, `created_time` could be used too. For accepting u need no reputation, you just have to click on the "right" mark. Am glad you cracked it!